# Issue loading gradle project from github on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I have a Java project build with gradle (with libgdx) and the project is stored on GitHub. I cloned a branch onto my system to work on, but I cannot get eclipse to load it right. In a previous branch I was working on it loaded correctly with four main folders for core, desktop, server and html. Instead with this branch they are all loading in a main project file as shown in the picture below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To8jV.png)

Also it isn't loading src and other packages as the java packages, and instead showing it as a folder, so java can run as not package to run out of.

I am trying to load it into eclipse doing File -> import project -> git -> projects from git -> existing local repository -> the project on my storage -> next -> finish

I also tried file -> import project -> gradle -> existing gradle project -> next -> selected the git project -> next -> finish

Either option hasn't been able to load the project in correctly, like before even though I followed the same steps I followed for the previous branch.

I have tried to load this multiple times, even re-cloning the git project back onto my system and creating a new eclipse workspace, but nothing changes the outcome. I have the gradle build ship gradle installed on eclipse aswell.

Does anyone know what steps I could follow to load this java gradle project from github into eclipse making it show correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried importing the project into Eclipse directly from the remote repository?

Comment: Yes this lead to the same error

Comment: Also import the nested project `core` via _Gradle > Existing Gradle Project_.

Comment: this leads to the src showing a folder as well, and not as a package and causes the error "Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip'."

Comment: Have you tried *refresh gradle project* or *importing it from outside your workspace* like explained in the [libgdx documentation](https://libgdx.com/dev/import-and-running/)?
Usually importing it via gradle (just like you explained in the question) is the correct way. But there might be a problem because the project was already created. You could try to remove the `.settings` folder and the `.project` file inside the project folder and import it again. Otherwise eclipse may use the same settings as before and not the ones you tried this time.

Comment: I have tried refreshing the gradle project and importing it from outside thwe workspace, but neither fixed the issue. Deleting the .settings and .project didn't work as well